# Comparing ul's li text with a master ul and it's li's and applying a class to the li's which are different

Tags: jquery, css

I've been racking my head over this for a while now and can't find a solution.

First of I want to be able to do this in Jquery...

What I trying to do is compare the first li of each of the ul's with the first ul to find any differences and apply a style to each li which has different text/string. Then do the same to the rest of the li in order, second li, third li of each ul.

my markup without classes ( i dont want to use classes to select using jquery )

```
<ul>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>black</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>red</li>       <----this one
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>black</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>green</li>     <----this one
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>black</li>
</ul>
```

in ul number two, i want the third li to have a class added to it becuase it has a different string compared to ul number 1.

Is this possible without adding a class to each li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution as well.  I just grab the first ul and treat it as the master, although you could identify the master by class or id if you like.  I then compare all the others to the master and add a class to the ones that don't match so you could style those however you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpFrr/

Comment: Nice! I've been trying to get the code to run inside a div but it seems to always pick up the first ul on the page...

You wouldn't know a way to make it only compare inside a div then reset when that div closes so it can be run on another div?

I tried wrapping the code in 

$('div').each(function(){

});

eg. 
<div><ul><li></li></ul></div> <div><ul><li></li></ul></div>

Comment: It would probably be 'safer' to use marker class names to drive this so you don't have accidental matches but this is a revision that keeps it working based on just tag names and structure.  http://jsfiddle.net/sqLym/. The bit about the 'master' array and how it works for each pass is based on scoping and javascript called closures.